# does a double-hop wifi degrade video streaming?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, performance, video-streaming

I extended my home network to my daughters' next door. I have an outdoor access point mounted about 400 feet from there, and a corresponding client bridge mounted outside her home. Then I cable from the (EnGenius ENH202) client bridge to the inside, and connect to another AP inside her place.

So when she connects to her local wifi, she gets on my home network, gets an IP from my DHCP server, and can connect to the internet.  The problem is that her throughput is slow, evidenced by choppy Netflix streaming.

Is there a way to optimize this type of link for better throughput? I suspect that I need better routers but I would like to try any tweaks for better performance first.

Comment: I suspect you need a better outdoor wireless link.  What’s probably happening is packet loss causing too many retransmitted packets.  You don’t list the specific outdoor access point you’re using, is it directional? Or Omnidirectional?  If directional is it properly aimed?  (Directional would be a better choice in this case, if properly installed and aimed.). I doubt router choice makes much difference it’s all about dropped and retransmission of packets.

Comment: The AP is another ENH202, like the client bridge. According to indicators on the client side, the link is strong, and it shows SSI around -65 dBm, about 30 db above the noise floor.  I will look to see if there are any stats about missing packets...

Comment: @tyson, the engenious series has built in directional antennas with very sensitive radios. I would suspect that something is either interfering with the link between the Bridges, or at your daughters actual AP environment. I would suggest downloading wiggle wifi to a smart phone and doing a site survey. Check your survey on http://www.gpsvisualizer.com. now pick the best channels (non-conflicting) for both links.